# Regex to match a repeating pattern between two strings

Tags: regex, dataset

I have a dataset with repeating pattern:

```
----
MV: The Oxford and Cambridge University Boat Race (1895)
SD: 30 March 1895 - 
----
MV: Awakening of Rip (1896)
CP: American Mutoscope Company; 4 February 1897; 9237 (in copyright registry) 
PD: August 1896 - August 1896 
----
MV: A Chegada do Comboio Inaugural à Estação Central do Porto (1897)
PD: 7 November 1896 - 
----
MV: Exit of Rip and the Dwarf (1896)
CP: American Mutoscope and Biograph Co.; 9 December 1902; H24875 (in copyright registry) 
PD: August 1896 - August 1896 
----
```

Now, I'd like to take what's between first `----` and next `----` string and change `\n` to `\t`, so that each entry will be in the same line tab separated. Each entry then will be separated by `----` so it will be easier to read in. In the end it should look like:

```
----
MV: The Oxford and Cambridge University Boat Race (1895)    SD: 30 March 1895 - 
----
MV: Awakening of Rip (1896) CP: American Mutoscope Company; 4 February 1897; 9237 (in copyright registry)   PD: August 1896 - August 1896 
----
MV: A Chegada do Comboio Inaugural à Estação Central do Porto (1897)    PD: 7 November 1896 - 
----
MV: Exit of Rip and the Dwarf (1896)    CP: American Mutoscope and Biograph Co.; 9 December 1902; H24875 (in copyright registry)    PD: August 1896 - August 1896 
----
```

I already tried with some positive lookbehind patterns, but no luck.

Comment: Ok I managed to do the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/xC7qJ2/5 but I'm struggling to replace \n with \t in the match using sed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something with both [negative lookaheads and lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Like this:

```
(?<!----)\n(?!----)
```

Then just replace the matches with a `\t` and you're done.

[Demo on Regex101 (modification of yours)](https://regex101.com/r/xC7qJ2/6)